# Why does behat say my class is redeclared in multi-suite test environment?

Tags: php, magento-1.9, behat

I defined two suites in my `behat.yml` and when I try to run `bin/behat --suite=system` I get following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class SystemContext in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test.dev/features/bootstrap/SystemContex.php on line 12
```

I used [this howto](http://www.magecasts.io/tdd/behat-part3.html). And my IDE says there is no occurrence of this class anywhere else. So I guess it tries to call the context file twice - but why?

**behat.yml**

```
default:
  suites:
    site:
      paths: [ %paths.base%/features/site ]
      contexts: [ SiteContext ]
    system:
      paths: [ %paths.base%/features/system ]
      contexts: [ SystemContex ]
  extensions:
        MageTest\MagentoExtension\Extension: ~
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            base_url: 'http://test.dev/'
            selenium2:
               wd_host: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
               browser: firefox
```

**check_baseurl.feature**

```
Feature: Testing that behat and magento are working together
  In order to continue working on Magento
  As a magento developer       I need to be able to configure behat and magento

  Scenario: Base URL is configured in the database
    Given there is a base_url configuration option set
    Then I should see the value being "http://test.dev/"
```

**SystemContext.php**

```
use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;
use Behat\Behat\Context\SnippetAcceptingContext;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\PyStringNode;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\TableNode;
use MageTest\MagentoExtension\Context\MagentoContext;

/**
 * Defines application features from the specific context.
 */
class SystemContext extends MagentoContext implements Context, SnippetAcceptingContext {

    private $baseUrl;

    /**     
     * @Given there is a base_url configuration option set     
     */
    public function thereIsABaseUrlConfigurationOptionSet() {
        $this->baseUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl();
    }

    /**     
     * @Then I should see the value being :arg1
     */
    public function iShouldSeeTheValueBeing($arg1) {
        expect($this->baseUrl)->toBe($arg1);
    }
}
```

Comment: From error message - your class name is `BackendContext` but file name is `BackendContex.php`.

Comment: @IgorLantushenko sorry, was a c&p mistake. I edited it.